# NSString on switch case

Tags: ios

Instead of using else if like this

```
            if([screen isEqualToString :@"A"]){

               }
             else if(screen isEqualToString:@"B"){

               }
```

Will it work like this

```
          switch ([string isEqualToString:screen]){
          case ISA:
          break;

          case ISB:
          break;

          default:
          break;
       }
```

where ISA and ISB is defined like

```
       #define ISA [screen isEqualToString:A] and **will it be efficient**
```

Comment: No, it wont. It accepts only int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I most certainly don't think so. switch/case is all about numeric if/then/else cases.

However what you COULD do is the following:

Write a function and pass it a variable number of arguments (since objective-c implements C look up va_args for the syntax). Pass it the original string and the strings you want to compare to.

Inside that function, use a 'for' loop, which compares the strings one by one until it either reaches the end or finds a match according to your criteria.

Once either is met, return the index. And that index you can use in switch case.
A little example:

```
switch([self compareStrings:@"FirstString" Options:"@FirstString", @"SecondString"]) {
    case 0: //FirstString
    break;

    case 1: //SecondString
    break;

    default: //Not found
    break;
}
```

That should work. Regarding your function: Be sure to either incorporate an Optioncount, or make the options 'nil' terminated, because otherwise the function won't know when the end is actually reached.

Comment: or for that matter, why not use `switch([@[@"FirstString", @"SecondString"] indexOfObject:string])`?

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer is, as per ATaylor and ACB, no. Switches require integers and at best you'd end up doing a pointer comparison, which isn't the same as `isEqualToString:`.

Options for cutting down the syntactic heft and processing cost of cascading `if` tests are dictionary based — you could in principle fill a dictionary with blocks keyed on strings but then for most practical purposes you'd need to create the dictionary rather too often so I tend to fill with selectors. E.g.

```
NSDictionary *stringsToSelectors =
    @{
          @"A" : [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(doTaskA)],
          @"B" : [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(doTaskA)],
    };

SEL selector = [[stringsToSelectors objectForKey:string] pointerValue];
[self performSelector:selector];

...

- (void)doTaskA
{
    // etc, etc
}
```

If you wanted to be even more naturally dynamic than that you could even go with:

```
NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doTask%@", string];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
if([self respondsToSelector:selector]) [self performSelector:selector];

...

- (void)doTaskA /* etc, etc */
```